# Сохранить текущее состояние окон в emacs

Tags: c++, ide, emacs

Экран разбит на 3 окна вертикально, и крайнее левое вертикальное окно разбито на 2 окна горизонтально(вверху `occur`, внизу `shell`). Как сохранить это состояние чтобы каждые раз не открывать окна заново, не настраивать высоту и ширину и не повторять регулярное выражение в `occur`?